# Why my hyper on right-click open new windows convert bule with underline, how to remove this behaviour

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, href

when I right-click on a hyperlink and select open new window then that link becomes blue with an underline. I want to remove this behavior.

I already search on the internet and find that using `'text-decoration: none;'`

I can remove this happening but still it is happening.
I tried `text-decoration: none;` style at the level of the close on the direct `'a'` tag inside HTML (`style="text-decoration: none;"`) but still not working.

There are different states of link: Normal, Hover, Visited so I used `'text-decoration:note on Visited'`

```
footer ul li a:visited{
    text-decoration:none
}
```

in fact I used text-decoration:none at every possible code block,
but still only when I right click and select the link to open in new windows it turns blue underline

Comment: can you please add your HTML and css code?

Comment: Pretty sure i read that `:visited` is a function of browser memory and opening in a new tab won't record that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's weird, try this?

```css
a, 
a:link, 
a:visited, 
a::before, 
a::after {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 2rem;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript: void(0)">Be gone underline</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, Hao Wu your suggested code worked and it solved my problem, I just append a:link, a:visited to my previous code along with property outline: none and it worked. here is the code:  footer ul li a, a:link, a:visited{text-decoration:none; outline: none;}

Comment: Yeah, I think the main issue is you forgot to set it for  `:link`